# Buying only one Twilio phone number in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, twilio

I want to buy one phone number from Twilio which has the same area code as a customer. When I run the code below, sometimes several numbers are purchased instead. This is not ideal as it runs up my costs.

```
exports.buy_twilio_phone_number = function () {

 prefix = "+1415"; 

 return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
 client.availablePhoneNumbers ('US')
 .local.list ({
   contains: prefix
 })
 .then (function (data) {
   if (data == undefined || data.length == 0) {    
     reject (new Error ("couldn't get a phone number"));
   } else {

     client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create (
    {
         phoneNumber: data[0].phoneNumber,
     }).then (function (new_twilio_number) {  
       console.log ("new twilio number purchased " + JSON.stringify (new_twilio_number));
       resolve ( new_twilio_number);         
     }).catch(function(error){
        console.log ("could not get the number error");
       reject (new Error ("could not add phone number"));
    });

   } // end else
 }); // end then
}); // end Promise
} // end function
```

The function to purchase twilio number is called from a post request (after the user creates an account and hits the submit button). This is the gist of the code.

```
exports.editPatientPost = function (req,res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields){
       // process user's account
       buy_twilio_phone_number ()
       .then(function (twilio_number) {
           if (err) console.log (err);
                updateUserWithTwilioNumber (twilio_number, function (err, user) {
                   if (err) console.log (err);
                   return res.redirect (303, /'account_created');
                });
       }) // end then
      }) // end form parse
 } // end function
```

I think .local.list is the problem where it calls the .then more than once. How can I ensure only one phone number is purchased?

Comment: The `.then` function of a promise is only called once, so that should not be the issue. When is this `buy_twilio_phone_number` function called? Is it possible that whatever is calling it is doing so more than once? Can you share that code?

Comment: @philnash Thanks for looking at this. I added the code where buy_twilio_phone_number is called.

Comment: Do you purchase more than one number every time this code is called? My guess right now is that the user is submitting the form twice (possibly an accidental double click on the submit button, or repeated clicks if the page takes a while to load). The first thing I'd do is ensure you are disabling the submit button for the form after the first click. Does that make sense?